# How to use Manipulate for a Plot and Equation Simultaneously

Tags: plotting, manipulate, display

I would like to use [`Manipulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) to [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) a figure and also give me the result of an equation simultaneously. In my case, this is because the closed form expressions for the figure change as I vary the parameters, and including the equation will allow me to quickly know which set of expressions are being plotted.

I am able to do this by putting Plot and the function in brackets in the Manipulate expression, but this puts the output in brackets as well.

**Is there a better way to do this?**

Here is a MWE:

```
a[x_, y_] := x*y
b[x_] := Piecewise[{{1, 0 <= x < 0.5}, {2, 0.5 <= x}}]
Manipulate[{Plot[a[x, y], {y, 0, 1}], b[x]}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`Column`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Column.html) [`Center`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Center.html) [`DisplayForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DisplayForm.html)

```
a[x_, y_] := x*y
b[x_] := Piecewise[{{1, 0 <= x < 0.5}, {2, 0.5 <= x}}]
Manipulate[
 Column[
  {
   Plot[a[x, y]
    , {y, 0, 1}
    , PlotTheme -> "Scientific"
    , PlotRange -> {-1, 1}
    ],
   DisplayForm[b[x]]
   }, Center]
 , {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I needed - thank you!